# LXD: attaching to running container not accessible through lxc command

Tags: ssh, lxc

A broken update left one of my containers inaccessible from lxc command but I can login (ssh) into it.

I have an old snapshot but there is one file (a key file), only read by root, which I need from it and I'm unable to read as the default user.

I was wondering if there is a way to connect to that container using the lxc command and using the IP address instead the container name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Some of the directories (e.g. /run) are mounted in memory so there is no way to access to those files directly from disk. However, I was able to gain root access by modifying the /etc/shadow file (which is not stored in memory) from the parent system. With that, I was able to retrieve the file I needed!